# How create fold-left with 2 arg?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp

How I can write a fold-left function with 2 parameters (foldl-1 proc xs)? This doesn't work:

```
(define (my-fold-left op xs)
  (define (func proc start xs)
    (let ((start xs))
      (set! start (car xs))
      (if (null? xs) start
          (func op (op start (car xs)) (cdr xs))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense... why use `set!` here? what is the initial value for the result? and why define the function `func` if you aren't going to *call* it? To implement a typical 3-arg `fold-left` try something like this, noticing that the main advantage of `fold-left` is that it's *tail-recursive*, and we use a parameter for accumulating the result:

```
(define (fold-left op ini xs)
  (let loop ((acc ini) (lst xs))
    (if (null? lst)
        acc
        (loop (op (car lst) acc) (cdr lst)))))
```

If you really need a 2-arg version of `fold-left`, remove the `ini` parameter and set a default value for `acc` at the beginning, in the second line. Be aware that by doing this you're restricting the usefulness of this procedure to return only a fixed type of results, depending on the initial value of your choosing.

Comment: A reasonable initial value that isn't a parameter to the function could be the first element of the list (if it's not an empty list).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yep, it seems that's what OP was trying to do: `(set! start (car xs))`, but I'll let him decide that.

Comment: That's the behavior that Common Lisp's [reduce](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm) has when an initial-value isn't provided.